# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [version] not found on type [com.something.something.models.something] Where am I going wrong at?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

usually a error like this is because I don't have getters and setters for the private property in my model but I have those and still getting this error. The error is pointing me to my model file.
in my model I have :

```
private String version;
public String getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(String version) {
    this.version = version;
}
```

and in my jsp file i have :

```
<form:label path="version">Version</form:label>
<form:errors path="version"/>
<form:input type="text"  path="version"/>
```

but i am getting this error but not sure why?

Comment: Post the relevant info. This should include at least you <form:form/> tag plus a properr stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this for input :

```
<form:input  path="version" value="${version}" />
```